# android open sharing image and try to sent to any app, but i get media not found

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

API 28

Clicking share in my custom menu, and after opening the sharing environment and trying to share I get this error message "no media found".
please help

Sending media to another app failed
(by the way the normal sharing works well)

```
 if(item.getTitle().equals("SHARED")){
                            String url = Uri.parse(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()).toString();

                            try {
                                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url);

                                if(url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".jpeg")) {
                                    // JPG file
                                    share.setType("image/jpg");

                                } else if(url.contains(".png")) {
                                    // PNG file
                                    share.setType("image/png");
                                } else if(url.contains(".mpg") || url.contains(".mpeg") || url.contains(".mpe") || url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".avi")) {
                                    // Video files
                                    share.setType("video/*");
                                }
                                //share.setData(Uri.parse(selectedFile.getPath()));

                                //share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(share, "Open With");
                                chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                                context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
                            } catch (Exception e) { // For example, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
                                Log.e(DebugUtils.TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: `String url = Uri.parse(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()).toString();` -- that has not worked reliably in several years. Please use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
   Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.project.fileprovider", file);  
    
      if (uri != null) {
         Intent share = new Intent();
         share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
         share.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
         share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
         final PackageManager pmanager = getPackageManager();
         final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pmanager.queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
         ResolveInfo rInfo = null;
         if (rInfo != null)
         share.setClassName(rInfo.activityInfo.packageName, rInfo.activityInfo.name);
         startActivity(share);
 }
```

and let me know.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: **.dcs, PID: 14275
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.project.fileprovider
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:662)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:635)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:441)
        at tsg.dcs.MyAdapter$2$1.onMenuItemClick(MyAdapter.java:124)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I gave up the sharing option from the right menu

Comment: You have to  create the filepath XML and declare it in the Manifest provider -> meta-data. Than it will work.